auth0/nextjs withMiddlewareAuthRequired cause CORS issues on API endpoints
I am building a multi-tenant subdomain-based app with Auth0 and Next.js with Hono as router. I am using withMiddlewareAuthRequired in middleware.ts to protect my app and redirect users based on their subdomains. My middleware looks like this:
export default withMiddlewareAuthRequired( async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const response = NextResponse.next();
  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;
  const host = request.headers.get('host');
  const session = await getSession(request, response);

  if (host) {
    const domain = getDomain(host, true);
    const segments = host.split('.');
    //check for subdomain existence
    if (host.includes('localhost') ? segments.length > 1 : segments.length > 2) {
      //if user access url with subdomain and at root (example: abc.domain.com)
      if (pathname === '/') {
        //redirect user to abc.domain.com/main
        return NextResponse.redirect(
          process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? `https://${host}/main` : `http://${host}/main` 
        );
      //redirect to error page if user don't have access to the subdomain
      } else if (session && segments[0] !== session.user.org_name) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(
          process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
            ? `https://${domain}/error/401/unauthorized_org`
            : `http://${domain}/error/401/unauthorized_org`
        );
      }
    //if user try to access /main without subdomain (example: domain.com/main)
    } else if (pathname === '/main') {
      //redirect user to homepage
      return NextResponse.redirect(
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? `https://${host}` : `http://${host}` 
      );
    } else {
      return NextResponse.next()
    }
  }
})

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)'],
};


This works fine for protecting pages and API routes. However, calling API routes result in an error:

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3002/api/organizationFromId/org_IA9V4aMfsDJwcCkW' from origin 'http://abc_company.localhost:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

If I exclude api route from the protection by include it in matcher like so:
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|api).*)'],
};

Then there are no CORS error but the API route won't be protected.
I did add app.user('*', cors()) in my route handler (I'm using Hono).
const app = createApp().basePath('/api')
app.use('*', cors())

I did know about withApiAuthRequired
export default withApiAuthRequired(function Protected(req) {
  const session = getSession();
  ...
});

but it expect Nodejs req res where Hono uses context object so I don't know how to bridge the gap.
If I remove app.use('*', cors()) then both including and excluding api routes from auth0 protection procudes CORS error so I think the middleware is somehow intercepting with Hono's cors middleware?

As you have identified yourself, the middleware is intercepting the API requests and prevent handling of CORS.
You can protect the API endpoints seperately inside Hono itself by doing something like this:
import { Hono } from 'hono';
import { cors } from 'hono/cors';
import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

const app = new Hono();

// Enable CORS
app.use('*', cors());

app.use('/api/*', async (c, next) => {
  const req = c.req.raw;
  const res = c.res.raw;

  try {
    const session = await getSession(req, res);
    if (!session) {
      return c.json({ error: 'Unauthorized' }, 401);
    }
    c.set('session', session);
    await next();
  } catch (error) {
    return c.json({ error: 'Unauthorized' }, 401);
  }
});

app.get('/api/organizationFromId/:orgId', (c) => {
  const session = c.get('session');
  const orgId = c.req.param('orgId');
  return c.json({ orgId, user: session?.user });
});

export default app;

Now you can exclude api routes from your middleware and re-enable your middleware:
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|api).*)'],
};


Hi, thank you for your response. I forgot to mention that my app is using a custom created auth0 instance with initAuth0 so I can't use getSession directly.
Also c.res doesn't seem to have raw? Here is my implementation and it seems doesn't work as session is always null:
const req = c.req.raw as NextRequest;
const res = c.res as NextResponse;
const auth0 = initializeAuth0(req);
const session = await auth0.getSession(req, res);
